Number of phonons into a supercell
I am a masters student who's struggling with Quantum ESPRESSO for my thesis. I'm at the end of my internship and I think I may have done some conceptual error, which of course are linked to practical one.
I have made some calculation about phonons in the Gamma Point of a Supercell, now I need to "reduce" the number of phonons calculated in order to obtain the number of modes I expect from a Single Cell calculation, which I have already done, since I need to confront the results obtained from both approaches.
Do you have any idea about how to proceed?
(Since I am a newbie to Quantum ESPRESSO, it may be possible that this number-of-phonon reduction isn't necessary, if so, I'd be glad to find an alternative!)
Best Wishes,
Martino

Are you talking about band unfolding? AFIK, in nband, you can select how many bands you want. For example: if a material contains four valance electron and you select nband = 5, you will get one empty band and four filled bands (considering single unit cell). But if you do 333 supercell calculation, you get 333*5 bands. After band unfolding, you might get the band in single unit cell.

Hi!
Thank you for your answer!
In principle, yes, my issue is associated with unfolding but unluckily it "works" only for dispersion curves of phonon. I do have only calculated the phonon in the gamma point, I don't know to do.
